# Array e MIMEText - Python

Tags: python

Por que não é possível usar Array para adicionar dentro de uma variável do tipo MIMEText (msg = MIMEText(body, 'html'))?

Explico:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    for owner in cursor.execute("select * from orcam where Ccusto=? and anomes=?", row.Ccusto, cdate):
        print owner
    if owner.Vr_real > percFor and owner.Vr_Forecast > 0:
                    print(owner.Ccusto, owner.Grupo, owner.Anomes)
                    body.append("""a""")
                    print i
                    print body[i]
                    i =  i + 1
    try:
        msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
        msg["From"] = emailfrom
        msg["Subject"] = "XXXXXXXX"
        msg["To"] = emailto
        server = smtplib.SMTP('server',25)
        server.starttls()
        server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto.split(';'), msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
        print "Successfully sent email!"
        server.close()
    except Exception:
        print "Error: unable to send email"
        server.close()
        server.quit()
```

Minha intenção é fazer que toda vez que o "if" for verdadeiro ele vá acrescentando dentro do corpo de um e-mail. 
Portanto, tentei fazer em forma de array, ele até adiciona as mensagens dentro do array body, mas na hora de adicionar dentro do MIMEText ele me traz o erro.

```
['a', 'a', 'a']
Error: unable to send email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\orcam_1.py", line 71, in <module>
    server.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Existe alguma outra maneira de ir adicionando mensagens no corpo do e-mail, conforme for entrando no IF?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa passar uma string como primeiro parâmetro de MIMEText, não um array.
Daria para concatenar todas as strings contidas no seu array, de modo a formar uma só string, da seguinte forma:

```
msg = MIMEText(' '.join(body), 'html')
```

A função join concatena as strings contidas num Array, colocando entre elas o separador no qual a função foi chamada, que no caso é um espaço em branco.
Você poderia colocar qualquer outro separados.

Comment: Deu certo Luis! Só uma última dúvida, não tem como passar mais do que 1 MIMEText como argumento para msg.as_string()? Minha intenção era dividir o e-mail em duas partes. Uma dentro do if e outra fora.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem. Se você quer criar dois trechos do email paralelamente, basta criar outro array, um body2 por exemplo, e ir dando append nele para construir o segundo trecho. Depois transforma os dois em string, usando .join() em cada um, e soma as duas strings resultantes.

Comment: Uma outra coisa aí é que sua construção do try/except está mascarando a mensagem de erro real: o erro de "string has no attribute close" que voce tem sugere que há algo bem errado com o que vocẽ imagina que seria seu objeto "server" - mas como voce usa o `except Exception`` e nao faz nada com o erro desse primeiro bloco é impossível saber qual é

Comment: o erro real.

A minha sugestão é usar a variação `try/finally` do comando, com as chamadas   `server.close` e `server.quit` dentro do bloco finally - e deixar a exceção acontecer, sem um except, pelo menos até voce ter depurado esse trecho. Depois que tiver arrumado, use  `except Exception as exc:` e imprima ou logge a variável `exc` dentro do bloco de Except.

Comment: @luislhl, basicamente, eu faria um outro join (string) e depois juntaria essas duas strings em uma, e depois passaria para o MIMEText, é isso mesmo né?

Comment: @jsbueno, obrigado pela dica. Farei isso!